# Can not access the AccountId field in the flow on Opportunity object

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, access, lightning-flow-builder, flow-builder

I built a flow on Opportunity in which I was accessing the AccountId standard field. but suddenly now I am not able to access that field from the flow. I checked with the access issues also, I have access to that field. the same issue with the flow I built on contact object also, I am not able to access the accountId from there too.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Check if FLS has been changed for your profile. It must be removed by someone

Comment: Hi Yogesh, I am able to access the field in the flows . Is this specific to Spring release issue. Also can you delete that filter and try to add again and see if you are able to access them. And check if you have read access on Account object.

Comment: Yes, I have the read and edit access, but still not able to access the field